# Adding a counter?

Tags: c++

I currently have a problem that I am working on that entails a recursive coin counter that does not include global variables or loops. I have gotten most of it down, however it seems that I need to add a single coin that is being counted, plus the result from the coins(sum-10), and I am failing to understand how to do that, as I have attempted to put a counter in for returning it.. Any help would be appreciated.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int coins(int sum)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (sum < 0)
        return 0;
    
    if (sum == 0)
        return 0;
    
    if (sum >= 25)
    {
        return sum + coins(sum - 25);
        return count++;
    }
    else if (sum >= 10)
    {
        return sum + coins(sum - 10);
        return count++;
    }
    else if (sum >= 5)
    {
        return sum + coins(sum - 5);
        return count++;
    }
    else if (sum >= 1)
    {
        return sum + coins(sum - 1);
        return count++;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int cents, n;
    
    // Get user input
    
    cout << "Enter an amount in cents: ";
    cin >> cents;
    
    // Call recursive function
    
    n = coins(cents);
    cout << endl;
    
    // Output results
    
    cout << n << " coins" << endl;
}
```

Here is an example of expected output

```
Enter an amount in cents: 16
10 5 1
3 coins
```

and here is what I am currently getting

```
Enter an amount in cents: 37

0 coins
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish by having consecutive `return` statements? `return count++`; will never run since it is always preceded by another `return`. And what is `count`? It doesn't look like it is declared anywhere.

Comment: Discuss with your [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what happens with code placed after a `return` statement.

Comment: Please add an example of input -> expected output.

Comment: I think you want to return `1 + coins(sum - 1);`, `1 + coins(sum - 5);`, `1 + coins(sum - 10);` and `1 + coins(sum - 25);`

Comment: Also discuss the effect of the `int count = 0;` up at the top of the `coins` function on the value of `count` in each call to `coins`. Duckie doesn't think it should be in the function, so the discussion might get heated.

Comment: Thank you JuanR, that was exactly it, it works as expected now

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can run the program at your speed and watch exactly what happens to the program as the computer does it. Typical usage is step through the problem area in the code, which may be the whole program until you narrow things down a little, line by line, keeping an eye out for the program doing something unexpected like storing the wrong value or taking the wrong path. The unexpected is a bug in the program or in your expectations. Either needs to be fixed.

Comment: The way to indicate that your question has been solved is to accept an answer, not by editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the value you want to divide into coins and the amount of coins. This:

```
 return sum + coins(sum - 25);
```

Does not make sense. You are adding unrelated quantities. `sum` is the amount of money while `coins` returns the number of coins. You need no additional counter, the return value accumualated during the recursion is the counter:

```
int coins(int sum)
{
    if (sum < 0)
        return 0;
    
    if (sum == 0)
        return 0;
    
    if (sum >= 25)
    {
        return 1 + coins(sum - 25);
    }
    else if (sum >= 10)
    {
        return 1 + coins(sum - 10);
    }
    else if (sum >= 5)
    {
        return 1 + coins(sum - 5);
    }
    else //(sum >= 1)
    {
        return 1 + coins(sum - 1);
    }
}
```

Each time you decrement the `sum` one coin is added.

---

This:

```
return sum + coins(sum - 25);
return count++;
```

Cannot be correct. Code after the first `return` is never executed. Also note that `main` must return `int`.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, recursion here makes the code more complicated. Unless you're **required** to write this recursively, it should be done with a small series of loops:

```
int coins(int sum) {
    int count = 0;
    while (sum >= 25) {
        ++count;
        sum -= 25;
    }
    while (sum >= 10) {
        ++count;
        sum -= 10;
    }
    while (sum >= 5) {
        ++count;
        sum -= 5;
    }
    while (sum >= 1) {
        ++count;
        sum -= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Or, even better:

```
int coins(int sum) {
    int count = 0;
    count += sum % 25;
    sum /= 25;
    count += sum % 10;
    sum /= 10;
    count += sum % 5;
    sum /= 5;
    count += sum;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: The question does mention that loops are forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to count the number of coins it takes to make up the sum provided, and to do it recursively.

Every time you use recursion you need a base case which does not recursively call the function. In this case it's if your sum is zero or less.

```cpp
int coins(int sum) {
    if (sum <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now, we just need to handle the other cases, where we'll use the recursive call to update the data so we converge on the base case. *I'm going to write code for quarters and let you fill in the rest of the logic.*

```cpp
int coins(int sum) {
    if (sum <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (sum >= 25) {
        return 1 + coins(sum - 25);
    }
    else if (sum >= 10) {
        ...
    }
    else if (sum >= 5) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

**One more thing**

If we step through this for an initial value of `97`, let's look at what happens.

```
coins(97)
1 + coins(72)
1 + 1 + coins(47)
1 + 1 + 1 + coins(22)
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + coins(12)
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + coins(2)
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + coins(1)
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + coins(0)
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
7
```

We can use integer division to reduce the number of recursive calls.

```cpp
int coins(int sum) {
    if (sum <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (sum >= 25) {
        int quarters = sum / 25;
        return quarters + coins(sum - 25 * quarters);
    }
    else if (sum >= 10) {
        ...
    }
    else if (sum >= 5) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, if we start with `97` we get:

```
coins(97)
3 + coins(22)
3 + 2 + coins(2)
3 + 2 + 2 + 0
7
```

Use a **much** larger number, and this has a significant impact on your stack usage. And integer division doesn't seem to be prohibited by your requirements.

**Just for fun**

For fun let's rewrite this using the ternary operator:

```cpp
int coins(int sum) {
    return sum <= 0 ? 0 :
           sum >= 25 ? sum / 25 + coins(sum - sum / 25 * 25) :
           sum >= 10 ? sum / 10 + coins(sum - sum / 10 * 10) :
           sum >=  5 ? sum /  5 + coins(sum - sum /  5 *  5) :
                       sum;
}
```

Comment: If you're concerned with stack usage with large arguments, it might be worth writing a helper function that takes the count of already-allocated coins as an argument so you can get enable tail recursion going.

Comment: You could do that with something like `int coins(int sum, int num_coins=0)`, but using integer math here means it'll never call itself more than the number of times there are different coins.